# Dell PowerConnect 2824 - DHCP takes 30 - 40 seconds to respond

Tags: dhcp, dell-powerconnect

I have a very strange problem.  DHCP requests (to my router, going through my PowerConnect switch) take 35 - 40 seconds.

Here is my setup:

Router (pfSense) --> PowerConnect 2824 switch --> LAN

DHCP server is disabled on the PowerConnect 2824 but is enabled on my router.  However, any requests on my LAN take 30 - 40 seconds to receive a DHCP response.

I've tried a different switch (Netgear Prosafe) and it works perfectly and I receive an instant DHCP response so I know the problem is not with my router.

Can anybody please help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably got nothing to do with DHCP. It's probably spanning tree. The switch is simply unwilling to enable the port until it confirms that the port will not cause a disastrous loop in the network. The solution, *assuming you know that the port will never, ever form a loop* is to enable portfast (or 'fast link'). See this link:

http://www.mcbsys.com/techblog/2010/02/gigabit-switch-spanning-tree-causes-slow-logon/

Comment: Dell calls this fast link.  And I do believe they default to having STP enabled and fast link off on all ports.  With some devices this can cause more than just a delay leaving the device unable to negotiate a network connection.  This tends to only happen with embedded devices which are less forgiving of odd networking behaviors.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That was the problem!  I'm going to have to read up on spanning tree to understand what exactly it's doing...

Comment: I never thought spanning tree would cause such a big lag. I currently have the problem that several workstations don´t install AD GPO policies.... because on bootup they don´t have a DHCP IP address yet.

Answer (score 3):

It's spanning tree. It's enabled by default on Dell switches. You can turn on portfast like this:

> interface range ethernet e1-24
>   spanning-tree portfast